# The dropdown list on this website shows a varying number of options when I open it manually compared to when I open it through automation

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir

I'm attempting to automate processes on `https://ttsreader.com/legacy/`. However, I've noticed that the site presents different options when opened manually compared to when accessed through automation. Specifically, when using automation, only a limited number of options are displayed, as indicated below.

[image]

However, when opened manually, the site displays 320 language options. I'm perplexed by this inconsistency. I've attempted to reference the same profile that Edge is using, yet it still shows only 6 options, as depicted in the earlier image. In contrast, manually opening the site, as illustrated below, reveals a multitude of options.

[image]

Can anybody guide me why this difference?

Comment: By default, Selenium opens up the browser without a profile or cached/cookied choices. I'm assuming that's the difference you are seeing.

Comment: @JeffC I attempted to load the default profile, but even then, it only loaded limited options. It's only when I open it manually that all the options are loaded. Additionally, when opening the Edge browser without providing any profile information, it still loads an empty profile it has created in the temp folder

Comment: Are you using the TTS Reader page as a signed in user or as a guest? Interestingly, even manually using the page, I get a different number options when using Firefox vs Chrome.

Comment: Yes, I have spoken to the owner of that site. He says that it differs from browser to browser. But all options are available only in the edge he says that. Manually and through automation I use that as a guest but option differs, when I use through automation only english options are left. Is it the same case for you?

Comment: Yes, I get the same behaviour as you. It's probably worth asking the site owner how they determine the options. That would let us figure out why Selenium is behaving differently.

Comment: Sure thanks. I will check with him. Also, can't we attach the already opened edge browser like the way we do for chrome?

Comment: @JustinKo You can see one answer now from Ronen Rabinovici he is the owner of TTS Reader. He says waiting works for him. Waiting works for you as stated in his answer? Because I tried opening the browser and then I started entering the url by myself and I still couldn't find the options. He says it works the only difference I see here is, he is using some other selenium binding, that could be the reason?

Comment: @JustinKo You can see one answer now from Ronen Rabinovici he is the owner of TTS Reader. He says waiting works for him. Waiting works for you as stated in his answer? Because I tried opening the browser and then I started entering the url by myself and I still couldn't find the options. He says it works the only difference I see here is, he is using some other selenium binding, that could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I tried the following code and it works as expected for me. Maybe the 'magic' is to wait a few seconds before the code executes so that the whole page - and specifically the voices have time to load. Here's my test code:

```
const {Builder, Browser, Select, By} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

(async function helloSelenium() {
  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser(Browser.CHROME).build();

  await driver.get('https://ttsreader.com/legacy/');
  await delay(5000); // Wait 5 seconds - so that voices can load.

  const selectElement = await driver.findElement(By.id('select_language'))
  const select = new Select(selectElement)

  select.getOptions().then(arr=>{
    console.log(arr.length);
  })

  await select.selectByValue('Sandy (French (France))')

  // Do not quit, so we can visually see the selected option exists.
  // await driver.quit();
})();
```

Here's my package.json:

```
{
    "name": "ttsreader-test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "npx mocha src/hello.js --timeout 60000"
    },
    "author": "Ronen Rabinovici",
    "license": "Apache-2.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "assert": "^2.1.0",
        "selenium-webdriver": "^4.18.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "mocha": "^10.2.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Ronen, Thank you very much for writing. But I tried opening the browser through Selenium Driver and then I used the wait for 500 seconds, while it was waiting I manually loaded the url in the browser but it is still not loading. Which Selenium binding are you using?

Comment: I edited the answer - added package.json content - so you can see there the exact dependencies & versions I used.

Comment: Other people are also trying, for an example, Justin Ko who commented in this question also states in the comment the same behavior happens for him as well. Can you please check out the mail I sent you?